# Удаление символа перевода строки в bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Всем привет. Оговорюсь сразу, я не программист, только учусь.

Задача следующая, нужно результат curl запроса записать в переменную, затем извлечь строку которая находится между двумя шаблонами, тоесть то, что находится между `<errortext>` и `</errortext>`.

Вот собственно само содержимое переменной,которое получаю в результате curl запроса

```
        str="HTTP/2 200 
    date: Thu, 21 Sep 2023 01:12:19 GMT
    content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    server: protected
    cache-control: no-cache, private
    access-control-allow-origin: *
    access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
    access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization
    access-control-allow-credentials: true
    x-ratelimit-remaining: 0
    x-ratelimit-limit: 1
    x-upstream-latency: 195
    x-proxy-latency: 1
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xml><result>0000</result><errortext>Success</errortext><balance>19.76</balance><type>Prepay</type><currency_symbol>$</currency_symbol><currency_type>USD</currency_type></xml>
    "
```

Далее обрабатываю с помощью данного выражения:

```
    str1=$(awk -F'<errortext>|</errortext>' '{print $2}' <<< "$str")
```

В итоге получается такой выход:

```
    str1="
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Success
    "
```

Далее с помощью данного выражения пытаюсь убрать лишние переводы строки

```
    str1=$(tr -d '\n' <<< "$str1")
```

И здесь начинается самый ад, который я не могу решить уже третий день с помощью всех возможных команд. Все переводы строки до слова "Succes" удаляются, но остаётся после него, из-за чего дальнейшая работа когда невозможна.

```
    str1="Success
    "
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему это происходит и как исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте `grep -oP '(?<=<errortext>).*?(?=</errortext>)' <<< "$str"`

Answer (score 1):

AWK делит входной поток на записи (record) и поля. Вы задали разделитель полей, а разделитель записей остался по-умолчанию, то есть перевод каретки. Соответственно, AWK в каждой строке ищет `<errortext>|</errortext>`. Если не находит,то поле `$2` пустое, и выводится пустая строка.

Вам нужно печатать только в том случае, если `$2` не пусто:

```bash
awk -F'<errortext>|</errortext>' '($2) {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
str1=$(echo $str1 | xargs echo -n)
```

echo -n должна убрать лишний перевод строки.
Xargs конечно создан не для этого, но... Ещё
варианты тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-bash-variable

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот такой `sed`:

```
sed -n 's|.*<errortext>\(.*\)</errortext>.*|\1|p' <<< "$str"
Success
```

Но правильнее использовать какой-нибудь xml парсер. Можно использовать вот такой небольшой скриптик на Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

str = '<xml><result>0000</result><errortext>Success</errortext><balance>19.76</balance><type>Prepay</type><currency_symbol>$</currency_symbol><currency_type>USD</currency_type></xml>'

root = ET.fromstring(str)
for element in root.findall('name'):
    print(element.text)
```

Если есть возможность получить не xml а json то можно использовать `jq`

Answer (score 0):

```
str1=$(awk -v RS= -F'<errortext>|</errortext>' '{print $2}' <<< "$str")
```

где задаём переменную `RS`(разделитель входящих записей) равной пустой строке. По умолчанию `RS` равна переводу строки.